# Generating 2 DOM trees in the same Web page

Tags: html, dom

In which case DOM, can generate 2 trees?
I had this question on a test and I said this happens when we have 2 htmls in the same Web page.
Is this true?

Comment: What do you mean by "two trees"?

Comment: http://www.webstepbook.com/supplements/slides/images/dom_tree.gif   that's a single tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do that, depending on how you define "tree".

- You can have an `<iframe>` in your document, but that tree will have its own `window`, and will not be directly connected to your original tree.
- You can have an `<html>` element inside your HTML (which is invalid HTML, but will still work), but that will actually be a subtree
- You can use DOM APIs to build a detached `<html>` element

Comment: creating a detached element would not create an independent tree, as the element's [owner document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument) would still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply instantiating a separate `Document` object, e.g. through [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), an XHR with `.responseType = "document"` or with the [DOMImplementation.createDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument) factory method would create independent DOM trees.